# Synchronously, how to make sure that google analytics tracking request was executed

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-analytics, click-tracking

Suppose I need to track my clicks using google analytics scripts.
I know that standard approach to ensure that tracking event was fired is to pass continuation into the tracking queue and return false from click event handler, like this:

```
 $('a').click(function () {
    var url = $(this).attr('href');
    _gaq.push(['_trackEvent', smth]);
    _gaq.push(function(){ document.location = url ;}
    return false;
});
```

My challenge is that I want to open this link in new tab. 
 
My perfect solution is target="_blank", but you cant do it with javascript.
 
window.open(url,'_blank') will popup new window in all browsers except firefox and this window is usually blocked by default.
 
This means that I **must return true** from the click handler.

So this is my reason behind the fact that i need to wait synchronously in some way for ga script to request it's tracking pixel.
Is some sort of [What is the JavaScript version of sleep()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/951021/javascript-sleep) function can help me?

Thank you!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The only reason you want to ensure the tracking pixel is fired off before visitor is taken to new page, is for links that take you to a new page *within the same window*.  In other words, you want to make sure the tracking code does its thing before the current window is unloaded.

If your link is opening a new window...regardless of how you are opening the new window...you don't need to worry about this sort of thing, because your current window is not being unloaded.

Comment: I did the same exact thing. Kept thinking my links were not _blank. +1